# Sorting a list of lists based on nth element, then n+1th element, etc

Tags: sorting, lisp, common-lisp, polynomials

My basic problem is that I have a list of lists that represent polynominals functions and I want to sort them based on the variable and then the exponent.

So for example variable 'x' before variable 'y' and variable 'x^n' before variable 'x^n-1'.

I have a function 'merge' which with the following input:

```
(merge '((5 x 2)(3 x 2)(10 x 2)(15 x 2)(20 x 2)))
```

Will result in this output

```
(53 X 2)
```

53 is the coefficient, x is the variable and 2 is the exponent. I can sort by the variable to get first all of the a's and then b's and then c's etc. but I don't know how to switch around the exponents afterwards.

Comment: This seems to be about the language _Common Lisp_, not about one of its implementations (_GNU CLisp_).

Comment: Could you please show exactly how you represent your polynomials, and in what way you want to sort the terms?  Example: 2 x^3 + 3 y^3 + 4 x^2 y + 5 x y^2 + 6 x y + 7 x + 8 y + 9.

Comment: Input: `(pplus '((5 x 4)(3 y 2)(10 x 2)(15 x 3)(20 y 2)) '((5 x 3)(3 y 3)(10 x 4)(15 x 4)(20 y 5)))` then i want the output to be `((30 X 4) (20 X 3) (10 X 2) (20 Y 5) (3 Y 3) (23 Y 2))`

Comment: So, there are no mixed terms in the inputs?

Comment: @WillNess: That is not what I meant.  I meant something like `3xy`, where more than one variable appears in one summand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two criteria to sort by, you can first sort by the secondary, then stable-sort by the primary criterion:

```
(stable-sort (sort polynomial #'< :key #'third)
             #'string<
             :key #'second)
```

(You can compare symbols with `string<` because symbols are *string designators*.)

If you have a more complicated function that defines the order, define that separately, for example:

```
(sort polynomial #'term<)

(defun term< (term0 term1)
  (if (string= (second term0) (second term1))
      (< (third term0) (third term1))
      (string< (second term0) (second term1))))
```

Comment: Well if i had 4x^3y^2 then i would want to search by the 3 then x then 2 then y but for "infinite" amount of variables. How would I go about doing that for so many different search criteria?

Comment: If I read your comment under the question correctly, you want to sort (not search) by the variable name, then the power, then the coefficient, and your input would rather be 4x^3 + 3y^2.  What did you really mean?

Comment: I want to sort them in alphabetical order in terms of the variables (assuming all inputs have the variables in alphabetical order) and then decreasing powers. i.e. abc abd acd or a^3bc a^2b^4c etc.

Comment: could you post example input and output for your code above as well please

Comment: Just put one of your polynomials into the `polynomial` variable.  How would your _represent_ a polynomial with mixed terms?